# How to make a "go back" button change state in home screen

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, router

So ive got a list of restaurant names (say fetched from an api). When I click on a restaurant name, I want it to link to a profile page for that specific restaurant, and this would set the text as "selected". And when I click "Go back" on that profile page to return to the home page, I want the that restaurant name to say "not selected".

So, if I click on the restaurant name, then in the profile page go back to the home page, the restaurant will show "unselected" since it was selected in the home page, then unselected in the profile page. However, if I click on the restaurant name, then instead of going back to the home page by clicking the "go back", I type in the url of the home page, it will show "selected".

I'm struggling with making it so when I click "Go back", the home page shows the restaurant name as having "unselected".

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-williams-2snv1c?file=/src/App.js

(I would also appreciate if I could get the name of this sort of concept so I can look it up myself)

Comment: I don't know what any issue is with the code, but it appears the code in that linked sandbox does what you describe. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the question, sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: I see, you are using `wouter` and not `react-router`. From what I can tell from the docs there's not a way to pass state along with route transitions (*to inform the `App` component a link from the `Detail` component was clicked*). If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want to set some "selected" state, and only clear it if the link from the detail page is clicked. How open are you to using a React Context? I think I can get to a working solution using one but if you're not interested I won't waste our time with it.

Comment: @DrewReese Yepp, that's exactly what I want. I'm open to using React context. Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want to set some "selected" state, and only clear it if the link from the detail page is clicked.

You can create a React Context to hold and provide out the `clickedRestaurants` state and updater functions.

The idea here is to use the `selectRestaurant` handler when navigating "forward" to the details page, and use the `deselectRestaurant` handler ***only when*** the link from the details page *back* to the home page is clicked. If a user navigates to the home page using any other method, the restaurant won't be de-selected.

The localStorage API is used to persist state changes and initialize the state. The resolves persisting the selected restaurants state when the page is reloaded or a user directly mutates the URL in the address bar, i.e. like manually navigating back to `"/"`.

RestaurantProvider

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const RestaurantContext = createContext();

export const useRestaurantContext = () => useContext(RestaurantContext);

const RestaurantProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [clickedRestaurants, setClickedRestaurants] = useState(() => {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("clickedRestaurants")) ?? {};
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(
      "clickedRestaurants",
      JSON.stringify(clickedRestaurants)
    );
  }, [clickedRestaurants]);

  const setRestaurantState = (id, selected) => {
    setClickedRestaurants((ids) => ({
      ...ids,
      [id]: selected
    }));
  };

  const selectRestaurant = (id) => setRestaurantState(id, true);
  const deselectRestaurant = (id) => setRestaurantState(id, false);

  return (
    <RestaurantContext.Provider
      value={{ clickedRestaurants, selectRestaurant, deselectRestaurant }}
    >
      {children}
    </RestaurantContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default RestaurantProvider;
```

index.js - Import and wrap the application components with the `RestaurantProvider` component created above.

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import RestaurantProvider from "./RestaurantProvider";
import App from "./App";
import Details from "./details";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <RestaurantProvider>
      <App />
      <Details />
    </RestaurantProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

App - Import and use the `useRestaurantContext` hook to access the state and updater functions.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Link, Route } from "wouter";
import data from "./data";
import { useRestaurantContext } from "./RestaurantProvider";

export default function App() {
  const { clickedRestaurants, selectRestaurant } = useRestaurantContext();

  return (
    <Route path="/">
      <div className="App">
        {data.map((restaurant) => {
          return (
            <Button
              key={restaurant}
              restaurant={restaurant}
              hasBeenClicked={clickedRestaurants[restaurant]}
              setClicked={() => selectRestaurant(restaurant)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </Route>
  );
}

function Button({ restaurant, hasBeenClicked, setClicked }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Link href={`/restaurant/${restaurant}`} onClick={setClicked}>
        <button>{restaurant}</button>
      </Link>
      <p>
        {restaurant} has {hasBeenClicked ? "" : "not "}been selected
      </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Details

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Link, Route } from "wouter";
import { useRestaurantContext } from "./RestaurantProvider";

export default function Details() {
  const { deselectRestaurant } = useRestaurantContext();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Route path="/restaurant/:name">
        {(params) => {
          const restaurant = decodeURI(params.name);
          return (
            <Link href="/" onClick={() => deselectRestaurant(restaurant)}>
              {restaurant} Go back and unselect
            </Link>
          );
        }}
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-make-a-go-back-button-change-state-in-home-screen]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define some sort of [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) if you want to be able to tell what has been clicked by the user and what hasn't. Here is one way to do it:

`App.js`

```js
import "./styles.css";
import data from "./data";
import { Link, Route } from "wouter";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [clickedRestaurants, setClickedRestaurants] = useState([])

  return (
    <Route path="/">
      <div className="App">
        {data.map((restaurant) => {
          return (
            <Button
              restaurant={restaurant}
              hasBeenClicked={clickedRestaurants.includes(restaurant)}
              setClicked={() => {
                if (!clickedRestaurants.includes(restaurant)) {
                  setClickedRestaurants([...clickedRestaurants, restaurant])
                }
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </Route>
  );
}

function Button({ restaurant, hasBeenClicked, setClicked }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Link href={`/restaurant/${restaurant}`} onClick={setClicked}>
        <button>{restaurant}</button>
      </Link>
      <p>{restaurant} has {hasBeenClicked ? "" : "not "}been clicked</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I more so meant that, when I click the button, the `selected` state becomes true, just like your example, but **also** when I click `go back` in the next screen, it deselects the button. 

So if you click the button to go to the next page, then go back to the home page, you'll see the button is not selected. However, if you click the button, then manually go back to the home page without using the go back button, you'll see `selected` is still true